Why is StringUtil not found with the latest version of jsoup on Android API level 21?
With the current latest version of jsoup (1.17.2), trying to run this code:
Jsoup.connect(urlToParse).get()

On an Android device, with API level 21, execution results in a NoClassDefFoundError:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.internal.StringUtil$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0
    at org.jsoup.internal.StringUtil.<clinit>(StringUtil.java:338)
    at org.jsoup.helper.UrlBuilder.<init>(UrlBuilder.java:30)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Base.url(HttpConnection.java:427)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Request.url(HttpConnection.java:585)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:139)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:79)
    at org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect(Jsoup.java:92)

Is there a solution to this other than using an older version of jsoup?
Running the same code on a device with Android API level 30+ works without any issues.


Is there a solution to this other than using an older version of jsoup?

Maybe. Through a process called desugaring, some of the newer Java language features can be made available on older Android devices. More info:  https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support
Android API level and Java version support
Android API level 21 is a codename: Lollipop release (lookup table). It's an old release, dating back to 2014 and is based on Java 7.
Android API levels 30+ are newer Android releases, all released in or after 2020. They all have support for Java 8 (newer releases also support Java 9, 11, and 17).
Problem
I've pinpointed the line of code that fails on your test device with Android API level 21. This is how it looks:
private static final ThreadLocal<Stack<StringBuilder>> threadLocalBuilders = ThreadLocal.withInitial(Stack::new);

More specifically, this is what's problematic: Stack::new. Method references are a Java 8 feature! That's why an exception is thrown on a Java 7 based system.
References

https://developer.android.com/build/jdks#compileSdk
Which Android versions run which Java versions?

